# django user_groups table missing

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I ahve a user model called TbUser and I have integrated a mysql legacy database with django. After doing migrations I have the follwing tables. `django_seesion, django_migrations, django_content_type, django_admin_log, auth_permission, auth_group_permissions, auth_group`

When I log in to django admin page, and click on the TbUser then select a random user I am getting the following error.

```
Exception Value:    
(1146, "Table 'db.tb_user_groups' doesn't exist")
```

Should this table be created when migrations are run?
Could it be that this table is the auth_group, and django is looking for this one using the wrong table name?

users.models

```
class TbUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=32, default=uuid.uuid4)
    username = models.CharField(
        max_length=40, blank=True, null=True, unique=True, db_column='usname')
    password = models.CharField(
        max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, db_column='psword')
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    role = models.ForeignKey(TbRole, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    department = models.ForeignKey(
        'app.TbDepartment', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(
        default=False, blank=True, null=True, db_column='default_super')
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    objects = TbUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tb_user'
```

admin.py

```
from app.models import TbDepartment
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import TbCustomer, TbRole, TbUser, TbUserRole

admin.site.register(TbUser)
admin.site.register(TbRole)
admin.site.register(TbUserRole)
admin.site.register(TbDepartment)
admin.site.register(TbCustomer)
```

UPDATE:

I have created in mysql a table called `tb_user_groups` and when doing the same action the next error appears

```
Exception Value:    
(1146, "Table 'db.tb_user_user_permissions' doesn't exist")
```

How do I generate these tables?

Comment: can you show your models.py, admin.py, and settings.py?

Comment: what part from settings.py do you need? I have added the models and admin

Comment: did you try makemigrations and makemigrate. if not then make some changes in your model such as comment anyone fields and run makemigrations and  makemigrate it will create the missing table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just use AbstractUser. It has everything configured, and you can customize it if you want. In this case you shouldn't get `tb_user_groups doesn't exist error.`

```
class TbUser(AbstractUser):
    
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = TbUserManager()
```

Comment: what is the difference of using this? i really dont remember why I have set to custom user

Comment: the main difference is AbstractUser has fields of django's User model while AbstractBaseUser only supports authentication features. For more details see [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/)